How to find the minimum set of numbers to remove for grouping the remaining numbers from 1 to 50 into equal products?
Bob had a set of 50 numbers, ranging from 1 to 50. He removed a few numbers and then grouped the remaining numbers in such a way that the product of the numbers in each group is the same. It turned out that he removed the smallest possible number of numbers.

Which numbers did he remove?
Provide an example of these groups.

I was able to come up with the following groups of numbers:
[ {5, 10, 6, 8, 4, 11, 3, 9, 2, 23} ]
[ {50, 48, 44, 27, 46} ]
However, I am not sure if this is the maximum possible grouping, and I do not know how to prove it in the general case.
Any insights or guidance on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

You can certainly add ${19,34}$ and ${17,38}$ to the groups. Consider each prime from $1$ to $50.$

Denote by $A$ the set of numbers removed by Bob, and by $B$ and $C$ the two sets that Bob has split the remaining numbers into, so that $A\cup B\cup C=\{1,\ldots,50\}$ and $A$, $B$ and $C$ are disjoint. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ denote the products of the numbers in $A$, $B$ and $C$, respectively, so that $b=c$ and $abc=50!$, and hence
$$50!=ab^2.$$
We see that $a$ is a multiple of the squarefree part of $50!$. We can easily factor $50!$ by counting to get
$$50!=2^{25+12+6+3+1}3^{16+5+1}5^{10+2}7^{7+1}11^413^317^219^223^229^131^137^141^143^147^1.$$
This already shows that $a$ must be a multiple of
$$2\times13\times29\times31\times37\times41\times43\times47,$$
and hence that $b$ divides
$$2^{23}3^{11}5^67^411^213^117^119^123^1.$$
This is an upper bound for $b$, let's see if we can attain it:

For each of these pairs, the set $B$ must contain precisely one number and $C$ must contain the other:
$$\{13,26\},\qquad\{17,34\},\qquad\{19,38\},\qquad\{23,46\}.$$
The set $B$ must contain precisely two elements from $\{11,22,33,44\}$, and $C$ must contain the other two.
We can make similar observations for the smaller primes.

We have a lot of leeway with the smaller factors, given the powers of $2$, $3$ and $5$. Then bit of greedy trial and error starting from the larger primes quickly yields a solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&\{2,13,29,31,37,41,43,47\},\\
B&=&\{13,17,19,23,11,22,7,14,21,28,5,10,15,20,25,3,9,27,36,4,8,16,32\},\\
C&=&\{26,34,38,46,33,44,35,42,49,30,40,45,50,6,12,18,24,48,2\}.
\end{eqnarray}
